# Invalid mapping file 'Domain.Entity.Restaurant.orm.yml' for class 'Domain\Entity\Restaurant'

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'm getting an error triying to map an Entity

I have this class

```
<?php

namespace Domain\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;

class Restaurant
{
    private $id;

    private $uidentifier;

    private $name;

    private $address;

    private $latitude;

    private $longitude;

    private $city_name;

    private $popularityRate;

    private $satisfactionRate;

    private $averagePrice;

    private $totalReviews;

    private $segments;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->segments = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getUidentifier(): ?string
    {
        return $this->uidentifier;
    }

    public function setUidentifier(string $uidentifier): self
    {
        $this->uidentifier = $uidentifier;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(?string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAddress(): ?string
    {
        return $this->address;
    }

    public function setAddress(?string $address): self
    {
        $this->address = $address;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getLatitude(): ?string
    {
        return $this->latitude;
    }

    public function setLatitude(?string $latitude): self
    {
        $this->latitude = $latitude;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getLongitude(): ?string
    {
        return $this->longitude;
    }

    public function setLongitude(?string $longitude): self
    {
        $this->longitude = $longitude;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPopularityRate(): ?string
    {
        return $this->popularityRate;
    }

    public function setPopularityRate(?string $popularityRate): self
    {
        $this->popularityRate = $popularityRate;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getSatisfactionRate(): ?string
    {
        return $this->satisfactionRate;
    }

    public function setSatisfactionRate(?string $satisfactionRate): self
    {
        $this->satisfactionRate = $satisfactionRate;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAveragePrice(): ?string
    {
        return $this->averagePrice;
    }

    public function setAveragePrice(?string $averagePrice): self
    {
        $this->averagePrice = $averagePrice;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getTotalReviews(): ?int
    {
        return $this->totalReviews;
    }

    public function setTotalReviews(?int $totalReviews): self
    {
        $this->totalReviews = $totalReviews;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Segment[]
     */
    public function getSegments(): Collection
    {
        return $this->segments;
    }

    public function addSegment(Segment $segment): self
    {
        if (!$this->segments->contains($segment)) {
            $this->segments[] = $segment;
            $segment->addRestaurant($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeSegment(Segment $segment): self
    {
        if ($this->segments->contains($segment)) {
            $this->segments->removeElement($segment);
            $segment->removeRestaurant($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

and this mapping file

```
Domain\Restaurant:
  type: entity
  repositoryClass: Domain\Repository\RestaurantRepository
  fields:
    id:
      id: true
      type: integer
      generator:
        strategy: AUTO
    uidentifier:
      type: string
      length: 150
      nullable: false
    name:
      type: string
      length: 255
      nullable: true
    address:
      type: string
      length: 255
      nullable: true
    latitude:
      type: decimal
      nullable: true
      precision: 13
      scale: 10
    longitude:
      type: decimal
      nullable: true
      precision: 14
      scale: 11
    city_name:
      type: string
      nullable: true
    popularityRate:
      type: decimal
      nullable: true
      precision: 4
      scale: 2
    satisfactionRate:
      type: decimal
      nullable: true
      precision: 4
      scale: 2
    averagePrice:
      type: decimal
      nullable: true
      precision: 6
      scale: 2
    totalReviews:
      type: integer
      nullable: true
  indexes:
    NAME_IDX:
      columns: [name]
  uniqueConstraints:
    IDX_UID:
      columns: [uidentifier]
  options:
    collate: utf8_bin
  manyToMany:
    segments:
      targetEntity: Domain\Entity\Segment
      mappedBy: restaurants
      cascade: ["persist"]
```

Restaurants are have a 0:M relation with segment , I tried map the entity with the relation but I get this error

```
  Invalid mapping file 'Domain.Entity.Restaurant.orm.yml' for class 'Domain\Entity\Restaurant'.
```

I'm stuck, I don't know what is wrong, what would be the correct way to mapp this entity?Anyone can see the problem because I don't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed part of the namespace of the *entity*.

Change this:

```
Domain\Restaurant:
```

To this:

```
Domain\Entity\Restaurant:
```